# Execution error : file 'rm1p0018' error code: 114, pc=0, call=1, seg=0 114 Attempt to access item beyond bounds of memory (Signal 11)

Tags: procobol

When I ran a script on HP-UX server then I am getting below error. Script is calling one executable file( rm1p0018 ) which made by cobol file.

Here is the error message from the log:

```
Execution error : file 'rm1p0018' 
error code: 114, pc=0, call=1, seg=0 
114 Attempt to access item beyond bounds of memory (Signal 11) 

HP/MF COBOL Version: B.13.50 
HP-UX df2hp405 B.11.11 U 9000/800 
pid: 12766 gid: 20 uid: 9831 
Wed Aug 8 08:52:19 2012 
8:52am up 2 days, 11:04, 4 users, load average: 0.01, 0.01, 0.01 
Thread mode: No Threads 
RTS Error: COBOL 
Sync Signals: COBOL 
ASync Signals: COBOL 
cobtidy on exception: False
```

Recently oracle database was migrated from HP-UX to AIX server with the upgraded version of 10g from 9i.

Intially application and DB both were resides on HP-UX server but now application is resides on HP-UX and DB is resides on AIX server.

Can someone help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hard to guess the cause of this memory violation.
If you are able to recompile the Cobol program, I advice you to trace it using "ready trace." statement along with $set trace directive.
You will be able then to have a trace of all cobol paragraphs executed and deduce the one where the program stopped and raised the error.